# ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_54: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Tags: python, python-3.x, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras

У меня есть такой код:

```
a=[[1,23,345,235,235,644,757],
[2,455,325,235578,23524,6413,757567],
[3,123,125,2375,23554,64123,75778],
[...],
[35,244,245,231235,2158935,6567944,7567557]]

b=[[1 0 0],[0 1 0],[0 0 1],[...],[0 1 0]]

c=np.array(a)
d=np.array(b)
print(c.shape)
print(d.shape)

input= Input(shape=(7,))
hidden1 = LSTM(10)(input)
drop1=Dropout(0.1)(hidden1)
hidden2 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(drop1)
drop2=Dropout(0.2)(hidden2)
hidden3 = Dense(32, activation='relu')(drop2)
drop3=Dropout(0.1)(hidden3)
output = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(drop3)
model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, 
          nb_epoch = 100, 
          batch_size = 128, 
          verbose=1, 
          shuffle=True)
```

Выводит:

```
(86, 7)
(86, 3)
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_54: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

Пожалуйста подскажите в чем ошибка.

Comment: Ошибка в том, что вы передает 2d массив, а надо 3d массив.

Comment: А как в тогда в моем случае поступить?

Comment: Например, если я поменяю строчку `hidden1 = LSTM(10)(input)` на `hidden1 = Dense(32, activation='relu')(input)`, то никаких ошибок не происходит. Ткните меня носом пожалуйста. И если можете, объясните почему он ожидает 3D массив?

Comment: Беда в том, чтобы вас ткнуть, мне надо или воспроизводимый код, который я могу запустить, либо весь trace, без него я не могу даже, где именно ошибка возникает.

Comment: Слой `LSTM`  обычно принимает на вход 3-х мерные матрицы. Если вы работаете с векторизованными текстами, то  чаще всего слою `LSTM` предшевствует слой `Embedding`, который принимает 2D матрицу, а вернет уже 3D матрицу

Comment: `vis= Input(shape=(7,))
hidden1 = LSTM(10)(vis)
drop1=Dropout(0.1)(hidden1)
hidden2 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(drop1)
drop2=Dropout(0.2)(hidden2)
hidden3 = Dense(32, activation='relu')(drop2)
drop3=Dropout(0.1)(hidden3)
output = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(drop3)
model = Model(inputs=vis, outputs=output)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, 
          nb_epoch = 100, 
          batch_size = 128, 
          verbose=1, 
          shuffle=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простите, задержался. Вот весь код:

```
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Embedding
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
import numpy as np
X=[[0.2597, 0.26142456, 0.259, 0.25940799, 23683.33027302, 7349.7516953, 16333.578577720002], [0.26053258, 0.26144444, 0.25922958, 0.26042, 37468.35797686, 15110.577669050004, 22357.78030781], [0.2614295, 0.2623595, 0.25968808, 0.261501, 35609.43035447999, 17452.80799378, 18156.6223607], [0.26159866, 0.26218068, 0.259, 0.26003401, 29310.877699889996, 14216.448366519999, 15094.429333369999], [0.261345, 0.2636776, 0.26012513, 0.26367634, 23306.719302679998, 10296.85594638, 13009.863356300004], [0.263, 0.2659901, 0.26183745, 0.26523, 20472.620550369993, 11517.402618899998, 8955.21793147], [0.26547842, 0.26698303, 0.26367346, 0.26562, 33721.81542282, 23136.27974657, 10585.53567625], [0.265388, 0.26726, 0.26456773, 0.26642, 31087.09787857, 14102.465529410001, 16984.632349159998], [0.266622, 0.26987374, 0.26569054, 0.26987374, 25040.094169600005, 15424.771387949992, 9615.322781650004], [0.26987239, 0.27490811, 0.26836316, 0.26963897, 64117.25057878001, 21727.852268989995, 42389.39830979], [0.27, 0.27799578, 0.26936737, 0.27705827, 38430.16810217998, 29568.57730271999, 8861.590799460004], [0.27649306, 0.27649307, 0.27114875, 0.27387104, 58586.746477270004, 45613.30578957, 12973.440687700002], [0.27317, 0.27328228, 0.27114739, 0.272, 36468.26466711001, 22335.37356814, 14132.891098969998], [0.272602, 0.272975, 0.27020169, 0.271607, 35545.41054462999, 13075.608538260001, 22469.802006369995], [0.271326, 0.2755117, 0.270788, 0.275, 42862.07223425001, 20128.944692099998, 22733.127542149992], [0.275, 0.27528, 0.27305015, 0.273685, 23317.74097547, 5905.05176192, 17412.689213550002], [0.27366, 0.27841472, 0.27366, 0.278001, 57976.254754509995, 30329.696638399997, 27646.55811611], [0.27841472, 0.27899833, 0.27420289, 0.27535, 24306.87031516, 13411.3943727, 10895.47594246], [0.27498, 0.27597699, 0.27304875, 0.27563, 21589.10892766, 5524.616931, 16064.49199666], [0.27533, 0.27739281, 0.275, 0.27654, 24692.53844407, 18090.29637307, 6602.242071], [0.27685301, 0.2777813, 0.275, 0.27583, 30267.427002099997, 15448.263191940001, 14819.163810160002], [0.275147, 0.27682342, 0.275147, 0.27681936, 24384.170368210005, 16376.703052769999, 8007.467315440001], [0.276, 0.27710361, 0.273, 0.273, 36398.22844947002, 24907.527999840004, 11490.70044963], [0.2745294, 0.27548847, 0.27112627, 0.2719999, 32132.935978259997, 20248.933901649998, 11884.002076610004], [0.2719999, 0.2763, 0.27018072, 0.2733248, 51226.18524559999, 31654.946940520007, 19571.238305079998], [0.275, 0.2775666, 0.27396384, 0.27701, 31949.554790759994, 15122.27919538, 16827.27559538], [0.27637, 0.27879131, 0.27494338, 0.27704, 41486.70650212001, 26509.693441990003, 14977.013060129999], [0.27642, 0.2774051, 0.27479603, 0.277, 35111.743895939995, 12394.543895940002, 22717.199999999997], [0.277, 0.28, 0.27693867, 0.27710001, 40888.60387258001, 19099.48709857, 21789.116774009995], [0.2775, 0.2862842, 0.2775, 0.28313176, 38513.324029949996, 25640.911343419997, 12872.41268653], [0.28313751, 0.28691713, 0.28152699, 0.282469, 61197.51847991999, 23325.688113149994, 37871.830366769995], [0.28193, 0.28329913, 0.2802014, 0.28151001, 29852.05468528, 14959.413685279998, 14892.641000000001], [0.282, 0.2855, 0.28151002, 0.2844817, 55910.71648824002, 38646.44131332001, 17264.27517492], [0.2844817, 0.2862842, 0.28200284, 0.282238, 37570.72962178, 18860.30516517, 18710.42445661], [0.28348, 0.28467942, 0.28174924, 0.28428926, 25910.926132880006, 20312.572089890007, 5598.35404299], [0.28252, 0.28399567, 0.27690307, 0.27856, 47741.09352186, 28323.83042893, 19417.26309293], [0.2786, 0.2827574, 0.27686997, 0.280388, 36037.60789362, 19021.83359562, 17015.774298], [0.28126241, 0.28132454, 0.27783902, 0.27786836, 31095.484588169995, 12686.073659529999, 18409.41092864], [0.27888, 0.28263643, 0.27888, 0.28219, 31008.63574314, 21604.4104149, 9404.225328240002], [0.282397, 0.284, 0.28076655, 0.280774, 28767.12543706, 19931.041291049998, 8836.08414601], [0.27979014, 0.28061, 0.2783005, 0.27918, 23599.820921080005, 10744.02091308, 12855.800008], [0.28018, 0.28231105, 0.279502, 0.281948, 27560.976517299998, 21587.3095173, 5973.6669999999995], [0.28065, 0.28329913, 0.28065, 0.28329771, 25648.548908520006, 10926.54425621, 14722.004652309999], [0.2832, 0.28429068, 0.28038081, 0.282342, 27003.19980656, 14473.20399943, 12529.995807130003], [0.28055, 0.2839625, 0.28055, 0.28219, 23239.45000078, 10033.263502779999, 13206.186498000003], [0.282, 0.28528382, 0.2809, 0.2809, 33977.38481012, 22567.58987056, 11409.79493956], [0.282956, 0.28419858, 0.28135, 0.28176703, 23822.65914036, 9457.15914036, 14365.5], [0.28371, 0.2852, 0.28174923, 0.283, 31018.538976599993, 14421.981788269999, 16596.55718833], [0.28174923, 0.28174951, 0.27672581, 0.27675288, 39983.33376085002, 17581.813597790006, 22401.52016306], [0.27771, 0.27922194, 0.2757, 0.2769985, 14766.862060359997, 8664.72311597, 6102.138944390001], [0.276, 0.27824522, 0.2757, 0.2763, 8084.727286100002, 3747.83545222, 4336.89183388], [0.27630429, 0.28019165, 0.27630429, 0.27941, 28903.792740159995, 17307.85641624, 11595.936323920001], [0.278465, 0.27968145, 0.27672581, 0.2775, 27634.795745639996, 14229.73371018, 13405.062035459998], [0.27714, 0.279, 0.27439162, 0.27556, 36102.76839415, 12810.434066590002, 23292.33432756], [0.27567, 0.27599087, 0.27301764, 0.27482, 29119.43572502, 13694.784071870003, 15424.651653149996], [0.27534681, 0.27801083, 0.27446, 0.277, 26941.697360170005, 9921.765610710001, 17019.93174946], [0.27785, 0.28062481, 0.27785, 0.27992, 33195.22520025001, 15345.79876597, 17849.42643428], [0.280299, 0.280299, 0.2772, 0.277898, 27782.507636479997, 14131.235232939998, 13651.27240354], [0.277534, 0.280142, 0.277534, 0.28014199, 27009.155570180006, 17402.611088079997, 9606.5444821], [0.27963, 0.28343895, 0.2780014, 0.28300899, 35679.690572679996, 24519.118245460002, 11160.572327220001], [0.28160253, 0.2822, 0.27964161, 0.281703, 23992.96768347, 11532.94571657, 12460.0219669], [0.280528, 0.28157, 0.2797, 0.2797, 22155.35184018, 7482.799999999999, 14672.55184018], [0.28137, 0.28167676, 0.2797, 0.28064, 24650.4872818, 13829.60712481, 10820.880156989999], [0.2797, 0.28213938, 0.2784, 0.2784, 23380.019638630005, 6820.57225763, 16559.447381000005], [0.278118, 0.27926, 0.27800141, 0.278618, 21825.6, 13677.9, 8147.7], [0.2789757, 0.28117992, 0.27846, 0.27985, 22874.41840068, 12868.918400679999, 10005.5], [0.280888, 0.280888, 0.27866628, 0.27982, 24166.605785, 12462.3, 11704.305785000002], [0.2789, 0.28021098, 0.2777, 0.2777, 21980.311145, 6979.27479358, 15001.03635142], [0.27936, 0.27982, 0.2778, 0.27966, 23549.847439, 10008.717439, 13541.13], [0.279953, 0.2813191, 0.27770001, 0.28016712, 24968.27942745, 14223.921314340001, 10744.358113110002], [0.27886, 0.27973, 0.27729809, 0.278, 23463.297349930002, 8064.49056523, 15398.8067847], [0.27718758, 0.28019922, 0.27718758, 0.27908, 23565.276137269997, 12499.43957812, 11065.83655915], [0.279896, 0.281313, 0.27919, 0.281313, 25183.822872329994, 13184.2398242, 11999.58304813], [0.28131, 0.2813191, 0.27964442, 0.28099999, 23960.897537210007, 8677.368053920001, 15283.529483290002], [0.28099999, 0.28274709, 0.27982148, 0.280195, 30899.213540260003, 18018.43194296, 12880.7815973], [0.280786, 0.2813899, 0.27869191, 0.28109855, 21076.004285770003, 15453.08686551, 5622.91742026], [0.2810984, 0.28211364, 0.27968, 0.281834, 19621.65303179, 10528.37649789, 9093.2765339], [0.280404, 0.28315162, 0.280404, 0.282485, 30389.417046650004, 21172.03820529, 9217.37884136], [0.283, 0.284, 0.28189, 0.282, 35378.04660218, 28276.498958120006, 7101.54764406], [0.28379855, 0.2838, 0.282, 0.28343, 25934.410614080003, 16811.35395502, 9123.056659060001], [0.2833, 0.2835, 0.282, 0.28279, 26372.423464009997, 7942.61098105, 18429.81248296], [0.283, 0.28361, 0.28220144, 0.28300153, 31009.94916985, 23174.27229463, 7835.676875219999], [0.2837, 0.2838, 0.28160253, 0.283, 33459.49385401, 10054.95631047, 23404.53754354], [0.282424, 0.28375576, 0.28150149, 0.281962, 30645.095918060004, 16516.42399394, 14128.67192412], [0.28184703, 0.284, 0.28160394, 0.28276, 39980.98818710999, 18695.62820111, 21285.359986], [0.28248, 0.28381693, 0.28094529, 0.28226, 25194.219057890004, 12384.10034424, 12810.11871365], [0.28136, 0.28315162, 0.28065895, 0.282558, 28568.39880644, 13366.801236439998, 15201.597569999998], [0.28315009, 0.28315009, 0.28133073, 0.28186, 26078.04937989, 8396.76730989, 17681.28207], [0.282292, 0.28247, 0.28112, 0.28228, 23389.6, 9858.4, 13531.2], [0.280934, 0.28314947, 0.28000002, 0.28027, 28000.19882476, 19211.48449476, 8788.71433], [0.280494, 0.28247089, 0.2791, 0.279851, 25297.18122269, 10622.46398321, 14674.71723948], [0.279342, 0.28117992, 0.2791, 0.280447, 22961.361987509998, 15178.72007481, 7782.6419127], [0.279488, 0.279488, 0.27672582, 0.278479, 48094.78673676, 15348.71315201, 32746.07358475], [0.278306, 0.27922195, 0.27691, 0.27855, 33922.53809246, 25327.632554, 8594.90553846], [0.27809, 0.27922195, 0.27711602, 0.27884, 22336.11480516, 10303.83483116, 12032.279974000001], [0.27894, 0.27999857, 0.27769435, 0.279, 26666.522157130003, 14478.494383510002, 12188.027773620002]]
Y=[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
X_train=np.array(X)
Y_train=np.array(Y)
vis= Input(shape=(7,))
hidden1 = LSTM(10)(vis)
drop1=Dropout(0.1)(hidden1)
hidden2 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(drop1)
drop2=Dropout(0.2)(hidden2)
hidden3 = Dense(32, activation='relu')(drop2)
drop3=Dropout(0.1)(hidden3)
output = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(drop3)
model = Model(inputs=vis, outputs=output)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, 
          nb_epoch = 100, 
          batch_size = 128, 
          verbose=1, 
          shuffle=True)
```

Как можно исправить данную ошибку?

Comment: Нужно было просто использовать np.reshape